# nginx conf for ignite web console in production mode

Tags: ignite, gridgain

In Ignite web console document page, it only provides Apache HTTP server conf for the web console in production mode, but I want to know how to configure it via nginx?

Answer (score 2):

Added [documentation](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/build-and-deploy#run-ignite-web-console-in-production-mode) for Nginx HTTP server configuration. Can you please try?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used the sample from "documentation" instead of mine, it works fine now.